# Modify Powershell script to read from a txt

Tags: powershell

Good morning,

I have the following script and it works just fine, but instead of hard coding 100 servers I want it to read the servers from a .txt file. Here is my code any help would be great:

```
[string[]]$servers = 'Server1,Server2,Server3' -split ','

$credential = Get-Credential 

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $servers -Credential $credential -ScriptBlock {

Get-ItemProperty 'HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*' | Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion, Publisher, InstallDate 

} | Format-Table PSComputerName, DisplayName, DisplayVersion, Publisher, InstallDate | Format-Table –AutoSize | Out-File C:\Temp\SoftwareListByServer.txt
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$servers = get-content servers.txt
```

Where servers.txt contains (only) a list of servers one per line.